# Spring dependency injection: Inject all instances of interface

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

How, if possible can I configure a Spring bean with all a collection of other Spring beans that implements a specific interface?

Example: I want to wire the `CarFactory` bean with a list of beans implementing the `CarManufacturer` interface.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
@Inject
private List<CarManufacturer> manufacturers;
```

Comment: And then you'll have to use util:list to inject the list.

Comment: @Thom - you use util:list if you don't use `@Inject` (in this case it won't work without annotations). If you use annotations, the list gets injected automatically

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to declare this in XML only without adding any annotations? (just out of curiosity)