# @Autowired vs @Inject injecting multiple classes

Tags: java, spring

What is the difference between this:

```
@Inject
    public GuitarPlayer(Provider<Instrument> ins) {
        instruments = new LinkedList<Instrument>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            instruments.add(ins.get());
        }
    }
```

and this:

```
@Autowired
    public GuitarPlayer(List<Instrument> ins) {
        instruments = new LinkedList<Instrument>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            instruments.add(ins.get(i);
        }
    }
```

I assume that in the first example every position in the list will be a separate instance. **If so is it possible to inject in my xml configuration file multiple classes which implement the same interface?**

Comment: Is it normal that one has `Provider<Instrument>` while the other has `Instrument`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7142622/1743880

Comment: I'm just following the example from "Spring in action " book and it says that when I'm using @Inject I need to use Provider also.

Comment: You can autowire a `List<Instrument>` directly if you have multiple implementations of `Instrument`. I don't know about xml because that's not needed anymore. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7725405/spring-dependency-injection-inject-all-instances-of-interface (works with `@Autowired` as well)

Comment: Thanks it solved my problem.